# Serialization lib for Java that supports object versions

Tags: java, serialization, jackson

We're looking for a way to serialize objects in Java that would be as fast and small as possible, but that will also allow us to change the classes as time progresses and still be able to read old object stored in the "old format".

The best thing we can come up with so far is Jackson. Any suggestions?

Comment: Unless your class is well-written to always provide default values (or equivalent logic) for data that is missing in the old versions, you should not use serialization directly. You may be better off use simple key-value pairs (e.g. serialize a Map) which will allow you to detect missing keys and take the correct action against it. Otherwise you should only change your classes through inheritance.

Comment: Is the goal to serialize as JSON, or just anything that would get the job done?  (I ask since the question is tagged Jackson, but the question body contains no mention of JSON.)

Answer (score 1):

The native serialization supports that. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/platform/serialization/spec/version.html